# LYFT requesting a ride returns missing parameters error

Tags: lyft-api

I am encountering an error that I'm struggling to fix.
When making a post request to :
**https://api.lyft.com/v1/rides** using the sandbox environment (and thus a server access token) I see the following response :

```
{
    "error_detail":[
        {"origin.lat":"Missing required parameter"},
        {"origin.lng":"Missing required parameter"}],
        "error":"bad_parameter"
}
```

which suggests that those two parameters are missing.
However, those parameters are included in my request as so :

```
{
    "method":"POST",
    "form":{
            "ride_type":"lyft",
            "origin":{
                    "lat":"37.773972",
                    "lng":"-122.431297"
            },
            "destination":{
                    "lat":"37.6213129",
                    "lng":"-122.3789554"
            }
    },
    "url":"https://api.lyft.com/v1/rides",
    "href":"https://api.lyft.com/v1/rides",
    "pathname":"",
    "headers":{
        "Content-Type":"application/json",
        "Authorization":"Bearer THE-SERVER-ACCESS-TOKEN-MADE-WITH-SANDBOX-PREFIX"
    }
}
```

Alternatively, the server sometimes responds saying the **ride_type**  is missing which is not.

Can someone please tell me what I am missing here?
I'm using a NodeJs server, with **request** library

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the node request library extensively, but it might have something to do with your json not getting serialized to the level of depth you need. Have you tried using [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)? It's a really popular http api that might clear up your errors. Your request would look like this:

```
axios.post('https://api.lyft.com/v1/rides', {
  ride_type: 'lyft',
  origin: {
    lat: '37.773972',
    lng: '-122.431297'
  },
  destination: {
    lat: '37.6213129',
    lng: '-122.3789554'
  }
}, {
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'Bearer <access_token>'
  }
})
.then(succ => console.log(succ.data))
.catch(err => console.log(err))
```